# Joomla 3.3.6 Administrator login not showing

Tags: php, joomla, html, administration, joomla3.3

First of I am a newbie in Joomla and in webpages in general, but am an IT guy. Here is my problem:

I have had a joomla 3.3.6 webpage first local and now I have published it to www.keeptravelling.dk, which went okay, the problem is - I cannot access the administrator page www.keeptravelling.dk/administrator - if you go here you will see that it doesnt show the login fields, but only shows a Joomla icon.

I hope you can help me! Thx!

Comment: If you use `control + u` to check page code you will see that there is a php error. I would suggest you to download joomla files from **joomla.org** and override them to be sure that there isn't something altered.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my issues using a joomla component called SP transfer